# Umbraco website throws NullReferenceException on existing objects

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I'm using UmbracoCms 7.12 for my website with `LiveAppData` Models Builder.

At the backend I've created required DocumentTypes(aka Models) and Views/Partial Views for them.

Following code of Partial View throws NullReferenceException on execute.
When I'm going Debug mode, the objects realy exist and calling testimonialItems[0] returns not-null object. Proofs are in screenshots below.
TestimonialsSection - is Document Type with Children of TestimonialItem.
At the backend I've created 2 children inside him.

The following code throws at `var testi = testimonialItems[i];` line. Even if I comment this line, it starts throwing `@header` NullReferenceException.

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage<TestimonialsSection>
@{


    var testimonialItems = this.Model.Content.Children<TestimonialItem>().ToList();

    var header = this.Model.Content.Header;

    var body = this.Model.Content.Body;
}


@{
    <div id="testimonials" class="testimonials-section">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="section-title text-center">@header</h2>

            @for (var i = 0; i < testimonialItems.Count; i++)
            {
                var testi = testimonialItems[i];

                <div class="item mx-auto @(i % 2 == 0 ? "" : "item-reversed")">
                    <div class="profile-holder">
                        <img class="profile-image" src="@testi.Image.Url" alt="profile">
                    </div>
                    <div class="quote-holder">
                        <blockquote class="quote">
                            <p>@testi.Body</p>
                            <div class="quote-source">
                                <span class="name">@testi.Header</span>
                            </div>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the debugger is not showing the error at the right place. I know it sounds crazy but it happened a few times for me.

Try to comment some parts of your code inside the loop to see which part breaks.

Maybe `testi.Image.Url` is null and it breaks your page. If you haven't specified any image, it'll likely be null.